# Maximum disturbance to space time of gravitational waves, and will this affect humans?

Tags: gravity, space-time, gravitational-waves

Do we have a theory that can tell us how much change gravitational waves can make to space time. If it is infinite then I think any time we can see biggest change in space time and how much could it affect to humans?

Comment: Related: (1) [How large could gravitational waves get and what effect could they have on us?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/15026/10589) and (2) [How close would merging black holes have to be to feel gravitational waves?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16353/10589)

Comment: I have edited your question a little but the sentence *If it is infinite then I think any time we can see biggest change in space time* is still unclear to me. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravitational waves cause a stretch and squeeze in space-time. It has two polarizations Plus and Cross polarization. This serves as an axis for the stretch and squeeze when a gravitational wave hits a body. However, the order of stretching and squeezing is actually really small. It changes space-time by an order of $10^{-21}$m. That's around the diameter of a proton. There are Numerical relativity simulations where you can see for yourself how much the change in space-time occurs for a certain pair of mass collisions.

Check out the Waveforms for SEOBNR, Taylor etc. You might get a good idea.

FYI : Question belongs in [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)